# PHP and JSON datatype in MySQL

Tags: php, json, mysql-5.7

Despite of [recent implementation of JSON datatype to MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html) I can't find any word on it in the related PHP documentation.
My question is: will PHP automatically convert cells of JSON column to the actual values - arrays or literals - or will it provide just json-encoded strings. Like:

```
$sql_query = "SELECT JSON_ARRAY(1,2,3)";
$result = mysqli_query($sql_query);
$value = mysqli_fetch_row($result)[0];
// what is a $value? Array(1,2,3) or a string "[1,2,3]"
// do I have to use json_decode() to get an actual array here?
```

(Don't have MySQL 5.7 at hand right now, so can't check it myself.)

Answer (score 0):

i think with [serialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) and [unserialize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) you get whatever you want.
so just store all values using serialize and you can get that values with unserialize.
so just check serialize and unserialize.

Comment: Converting data to string just for the sake of storage is not a question.
The point is to utilize the built-in JSON functionality which was recently implemented in MySQL.

Comment: personally i'm never using like this but googled it about it and get some useful links [link1](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html) , [link2](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html)

Comment: This doesn't answer OP's question at all. Plus, keeping data in PHP-serialized format is a horrible idea from the cross-platform compatibility point of view.

Comment: @utsav, you make no sense. The links you provided are MySQL documentation pages. There is zero information regarding to PHP. Not to say that the first one was posted in my original question itself so I am obviously familiar with that.